# Capistrano: How to share Capistrano tasks?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano, capistrano3, rvm-capistrano

I have some shared tasks between my staging and production deploy scripts. What is the best practice of writing shared tasks? Do I need to move them to a separate file under `/lib/capistrano/tasks` for example? And if so how would I do that? I mean what will be the file extension and how to namespace those tasks and access them through `cap` command?

Comment: This post is worth to read: http://vladigleba.com/blog/2014/04/10/deploying-rails-apps-part-6-writing-capistrano-tasks/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A typical multistage configuration of Capistrano would have the following files:

- `Capfile`
- `config/deploy.rb`
- `config/deploy/staging.rb`
- `config/deploy/production.rb`

The tasks placed in `staging.rb` or `production.rb` are available only in those environments.

If you want some tasks accessible by any environment, you can place them in `config/deploy.rb`.

If you want to extract them into a separate file, then just like you said, you can place them in `lib/capistrano/tasks/*.rake`. (Normally a `Capfile` should contain a line to load those tasks.)

For example, there is a customized task `unicorn:restart` which restarts Unicorn. We can create a file called `lib/capistrano/tasks/unicorn.rake`, and add the following the file:

```
namespace :unicorn do
  desc "Restart Unicorn"
  task :restart do
    # ...
  end
end
```

**EDIT**

You can add the following line to your `Capfile`, to load the shared tasks under `lib/capistrano/tasks/*.rake`.

```
# Load custom tasks from `lib/capistrano/tasks' if you have any defined
Dir.glob('lib/capistrano/tasks/*.rake').each { |r| import r }
```

Comment: I edited the answer to add the necessary information I was searching for, and marked your question as accepted. Thanks Domon!